Laravel: How can I access auth data in class Handler that extends ExceptionHandler
I am trying to access auth in register method from class Handler that extends ExceptionHandler. I have tried to add EncryptCookies, AddQueuedCookiesToResponse, StartSession in middleware but could not work. I need to access current user name in Handler if issue occurs in try catch.
In essence, I have developed a system that allows me to observe any production issues. The system is functioning properly, but I need to add the current user's name if an issue arises while they are logged in.
I am interested in either adding the user name to $e or passing a different parameter in the code below.  //$newLighthouse->add($e)
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of exception types with their corresponding custom log levels.
     *
     * @var array<class-string<\Throwable>, \Psr\Log\LogLevel::*>
     */
    protected $levels = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string<\Throwable>>
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed to the session on validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {           

            $newLighthouse = new Lighthouse();
            $newLighthouse->add($e);
        });
    }
}


Add the relevant code to the question.

@GertB. I have updated my question

I have used Auth facade for this purpose. This is how my Handler looks like:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
...
...
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
       $userName = Auth::user->name;
    }
    return parent::report($exception);
}

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
       $userName = Auth::user->name;
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}

You can use it in this way in your Handler class. A good practice will be to add a null check for your user name.

Auth::check() always return false

There should be a problem in authentication then. Please check how you have set up your authentication.
